# Move zoomed chart in c#

Tags: c#, charts, mschart

I am using the following code to create a chart

```
chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;
chart1.DataSource = dict;
chart1.Series[0].XValueMember = "Key";
chart1.Series[0].YValueMembers = "Value";
chart1.Series[0].IsVisibleInLegend = false;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.MajorGrid.LineWidth = 0;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "0.00";

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoomable = true;

chart1.Refresh();
```

and the following code to zoom in the chart with scroll

```
double xMin = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
double xMax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;
double yMin = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMinimum;
double yMax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.ViewMaximum;

double posXStart = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) - (xMax - xMin) / 4;
double posXFinish = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.X) + (xMax - xMin) / 4;
double posYStart = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) - (yMax - yMin) / 4;
double posYFinish = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.PixelPositionToValue(e.Location.Y) + (yMax - yMin) / 4;

chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.ScaleView.Zoom(posXStart, posXFinish);
chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.ScaleView.Zoom(posYStart, posYFinish);
```

I am trying to be able to move the zoomed chart with my mouse while I hold the left button.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are trying to use panning.  Unfortunately, this is not very simple with MSCharts.

The easy answer is to use the scroll bars to pan left and right or up and down.  Make sure the axis `ScaleView.Scroll` method is set to a proper value (probably `1`) otherwise it will jump crazy far every click depending what it is set to.

The hard answer is, [MSChart Extension](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/376059/MSChart-Extension-Zoom-and-Pan-Controls), someone developed a nice panning and zoom control for MS Chart and all the source code is available on there.  The bad news is you'll have to dig through the code to find what you want and don't want, but it's a nice control.